# Lie algebra's, Fourier transforms and quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fourier-transform, lie-algebra

I read somewhere about a relation between the Fourier transform and differential operators of the Lie algebra ${\displaystyle {\mathfrak {sl}}(2)}$ and how this somehow has a quantum mechanical interpretation in many cases.

I realize this is a vague description. But if anyone who knows what is meant by this could point me to some books or papers that discuss this, I would be grateful.

Comment: Read where? Which page?

Comment: Well, the [Jordan map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_map) is a functor producing the representation theory of sl(2), and even all  sl(n) Lie algebras, actually, by utilizing QM oscillators and their Fourier structure. But you have to be more specific.